# trouble reading a text file

Tags: c

I am trying to read a txt file with following contents:

test.txt

```
3,4
5,6
7,8
```

each pair is in one line. I want to put these values in an array. But I want the array size to adjust based on number of pairs in the test txt.

So I calculated the number of lines available in the txt file until `EOF` and assigned the number of lines to the array to assign the `sizeof` the array.Then when I try to read the file using `fscanf` I get some weird numbers which is not even part of this txt file like `2342,123123`.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc , char **argv)

{

FILE *pf;
int k;

int counter=0;
    int c;

   pf = fopen("test.txt", "r");

    if(pf==NULL)
    {    
      printf("its nuull");
     }
    else
    {
do
{
c=fgetc(pf);
if(c=='\n')
counter++;

}while(c!=EOF);


printf("counter value is = %d\n", counter);


int b[counter][2];

     for(k=0;k<counter;k++)
       {
     fscanf(pf,"%d, %d" ,&b[k][0],&b[k][1]);
    printf("%d,%d\n" ,b[k][0],b[k][1]);
    }



 }
fclose(pf);
    }
```

Comment: does the pointer moves somewhere at the EOF? i am not sure that it cud be the reason , but when i remove do while loop and make an array with b[3][2] , i can read the pairs correctly

Comment: Is there any way i can access the elements of array 'b' after fclose(pf); statment?

Comment: Any solutions please?

Comment: The array b will be completely unaffected by the fclose statement. The contents of the file are loaded into the array by this point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to call:

```
rewind(pf);
```

after displaying your counter value.

This will reset the file pointer to the start of the file.

Comment: Is there any way i can access the elements of array 'b' after fclose(pf); statment?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is probably that the current file pointer is pointing at the end of the file. You need to read from the begining of the file now, so you need to do something like:

```
rewind(pf);
```

There are other mechanisms -  for instance `fseek` or `fsetpos`, but `rewind` is what I would use here.

You might also check the return from fscanf - this will return the number of input items assigned. If this isn't 2 (in your case) then something went wrong.

Comment: Is there any way i can access the elements of array 'b' after fclose(pf); statment?

Comment: @james I can't really tell because of the indentation, but it looks like the fclose is called after b goes out of scope. - ie b is only in scope inside the `else { }` So, no, not as currently written.